# Intersect (inner join) two arrays with different key names

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, intersection

I have following two multidimensional arrays:

First array:

```
$array_1_data = Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => IT [slug] => it )
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Accounting [slug] => accounting )
)
```

Second array:

```
$array_2_data = Array (
    [0] => Array ( [cid] => 3 [jid] => 24061 )
    [1] => Array ( [cid] => 1 [jid] => 24062 )
)
```

Expected result:

```
$some_array = Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => IT [slug] => it )
)
```

I won't mind having `[cid]` in the result.

I want to intersect these two arrays by `[id]` of the first array and `[cid]` of the second array, like inner join in MySQL. I have basic `foreach` and `if else` logic for this purpose but speed is a priority now so I'm looking for non-looped solution. For better understanding here is the basic looped solution:

```
    foreach ($array_1_data as $array_1_row ) {
        foreach ($array_2_data  as $array_2_row ) {
            if ($array_2_row['cid'] == $array_1_row['id']) {
                //intersection iteration
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried `array_uintersection` as follows:

```
array_uintersect($array_1_data, $array_2_data, function($a1, $a2){
    $diff1 = strcasecmp($a1['id'], $a2['cid']);
    if ($diff1 != 0) return $diff1;
    return 0;
});
```

But it gives me undefined index 'id'. I checked this question: [Comparing two arrays with different key names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120731/comparing-two-arrays-with-different-key-names). First answer for this question gives a looped solution which I want to avoid. Second answer suggests changing SQL structure but I have no control over that. So,

Is there really a non-looped fast solution to this kind of situation?

Comment: can you show how should look the expected result?

Comment: In `array_uintersect()`, the function can be called with elements from the same array. That's why it gets an error, because they don't both have `id` and `cid`.

Comment: You can add an `id` element to the second array, making it a copy of the `cid`, then use `array_uintersect`. I don't think there's anything built in that does what you want.

Comment: Why don't you just perform the join when querying the database?

Comment: @Barmar: These are third party generated arrays, I don't have SQL controls.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using `array_uintersect_uassoc` function:

```
$result = array_uintersect_uassoc($array_1_data, $array_2_data, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp($a['id'], $b['cid']);
}, function($a, $b){
    return (int) [$a, $b] == ['id', 'cid'];
});

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => IT
            [slug] => it
        )
)
```

According yo your condition: *to intersect these two arrays by [**id**] of the first array and [**cid**] of the second array*, we should consider a *key comparison function* for those keys only `['id', 'cid']`.
Having the needed keys on each comparison step it only remain to compare their values(with *value compare function*)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect-uassoc.php

[**DEMO** link](https://eval.in/637562)

Comment: @JanakaDombawela, added some explanation

Comment: check your code for errors and pay attention for my DEMO link