# intersect multiple multi-dimensional arrays by a specific key and get result with all data from both arrays

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to get an intersection of an array with a subset of itself that includes more data. The result should include all fields from both array.

Example given:

```
   $arr1 = [
       ['id' => 1, 'country' => 'US', 'user_name' => 'test1'],
       ['id' => 2, 'country' => 'UK', 'user_name' => 'test2'],
       ['id' => 3, 'country' => 'IT', 'user_name' => 'test3']
    ];

    $arr2 = [
        ['cid' => 1, 'orders' => 100, 'views' => 3 ],
        ['cid' => 3, 'orders' => 200, 'views' => 4 ],
    ];
```

The result should be:

```
       $res = [
           ['id' => 1, 'country' => 'US', 'user_name' => 'test1', 'orders' => 100, 'views' => 3 ],
           ['id' => 3, 'country' => 'IT', 'user_name' => 'test3', 'orders' => 200, 'views' => 4 ],
       ];
```

I tried to use array_uintersect_uassoc as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383195/intersect-inner-join-two-arrays-with-different-key-names/39383599#39383599)

```
        $result = array_uintersect_uassoc($arr1, $arr2, function ($a, $b) {
           return strcasecmp($a['id'], $b['cid']);
        }, function ($a, $b) {
           return (int)[$a, $b] == ['id', 'cid'];
        });
```

but the result isn't including the fields from the 2nd array.

In my case, the 2nd array cid key is a subset of id key of the 1st array.

I'd like to get an efficient way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply loop second array and check first array. If element exists in first one, merge together using `array_merge`:

```php
<?php
   $arr1 = [
       ['id' => 1, 'country' => 'US', 'user_name' => 'test1'],
       ['id' => 2, 'country' => 'UK', 'user_name' => 'test2'],
       ['id' => 3, 'country' => 'IT', 'user_name' => 'test3']
    ];

    $arr2 = [
        ['cid' => 1, 'orders' => 100, 'views' => 3 ],
        ['cid' => 3, 'orders' => 200, 'views' => 4 ],
    ];
    $arr1 = array_column($arr1, null, 'id'); // Index by ID
    $arr2 = array_column($arr2, null, 'cid'); // Index by CID

    $arr3 = []; // Results array. Possible to merge back to $arr1 too

    foreach ($arr2 as $id => $a2) {
        if (isset($arr1[$id])) {
            $arr3[] = array_merge($arr1[$id], $a2);
        }
    }

    var_dump($arr3);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3b92d05f90f7d639d6b35111ac72403cba8b538)